# How do I get fabcar object response at offline process?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to know "How do I get fabcar object response at [offline] process"

I tried to execute following tutorial.

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-sign-transaction-offline.html

[fabcar]
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html

And I changed following source and make develop environment for fabcar, so I got success executing fabcar's chaincode.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.4/test/integration/signTransactionOffline.js#L178-L183

But I only got following response by sendSignedTransaction.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.4/test/integration/signTransactionOffline.js#L214

```
{ status: 'SUCCESS', info: '' }
```

I changed this test code following

```js
const transactionProposalReq = {
  fcn: 'move',
  args: ['a', 'b', '100'],
  chaincodeId: 'end2endnodesdk',
  channelId: 'mychannel',
};
 :
 :
const response = await channel.sendSignedTransaction({
  signedProposal: signedCommitProposal,
  request: commitReq,
});
t.equal(response.status, 'SUCCESS', 'commit should response success');
 :
```

↓

```js
const transactionProposalReq = {
  fcn: 'queryCar',
  args: ['CAR12'],
  chaincodeId: 'fabcar',
  channelId: 'mychannel',
};
 :
const response = await channel.sendSignedTransaction({
  signedProposal: signedCommitProposal,
  request: commitReq,
});
console.log('response is ', response);
```

"querycar" is following.
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/chaincode/fabcar/fabcar.go#L85-L93

I expected following response.

```
{
    color: 'blue',
    make: 'Toyota',
    model: 'Prius',
    owner: 'Tomoko',
},
```

But I only get following response by sendSignedTransaction.

```
{ status: 'SUCCESS', info: '' }
```

How do I get fabcar object response at offline process ?
Can I use some method insted of sendSignedTransaction ?

Answer (score 0):

I got exact response...

I should use following response.

```js
const proposalResponses = await channel.sendSignedProposal(sendSignedProposalReq);
```

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.4/test/integration/signTransactionOffline.js#L193